# How to return and array in a soap service?

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap

and i want to return and array of buyers this is my xsd file, there is also the definition of buyer
in the xsd file:

```
<xs:element name="getBuyerResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="buyer" type="tns:buyer" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="deleteBuyerRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="deleteBuyerResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="response" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="buyer">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" />
        <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

i dont know how to write the request and response for all the buyers in the application.

I am using spring boot,
java 7,
maven,
posgress,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `maxOccurs` attribute. For example, to return any amount of buyer elements in your getBuyerResponse:

```
<xs:element name="getBuyerResponse">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="buyer" type="tns:buyer" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Or to return a maximum of 8 buyer elements:

```
<xs:element name="getBuyerResponse">
   <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
         <xs:element name="buyer" type="tns:buyer" maxOccurs="8"/>
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Note that `maxOccurs` defaults to 1 if you do not specify it.